# How can i enable the feature: Audio passthrough with SPDIF and HDMI, including for Audio HD codecs, like DD+, TrueHD or DTS-HD

Tags: hdmi, libvlcsharp

By default, only a stereo signal arrives at the AV receiver.

After some time of searching I found: --mmdevice-passthrough=2

Now the AV-Receiver get PCM-Audio but it does not recognize Dolby Atmos.
[In VLC my settings are:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7dJI.jpg)

How do I have to configure LibVLCSharp for the same behavior?
Can I also use the same settings of VLC?

Comment: Please share more info such as platform and code

Answer (score 0):

The two functions that will allow you to perform this are likely to be

```
mediaplayer.SetOutputDevice
mediaplayer.SetAudioOutput
```

Some context https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=146797&p=481603&hilit=dolby+atmos#p481603

If you'd like to contribute a sample for this, that'd be great :)